Как превратить строку в нетривиальный объект C#?
Есть вот такая строка, приходящая в WebSocket:
["price_changed",{"id":"4243953","name":"AWP | Duality (Battle-Scarred)","class_id":"5434880573","skin_id":450,"suggested_price":1850,"asset_id":"38175556581","float_id":"14035657510494034055","paint_seed":917,"tradehold":7,"price":1750,"app_id":730,"old_price":1720,"bot_steam_id":"76561198260669567","float_value":0.46425825357437134}]

По структуре напоминает вот такой объект:
public class PriceChangedResponce
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public PriceChangedItem priceChangedItem { get; set; }
}

public class PriceChangedItem
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string class_id { get; set; }
    public int skin_id { get; set; }
    public int suggested_price { get; set; }
    public string asset_id { get; set; }
    public object float_id { get; set; }
    public object paint_seed { get; set; }
    public int tradehold { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int app_id { get; set; }
    public int old_price { get; set; }
    public string bot_steam_id { get; set; }
    public object float_value { get; set; }
}

Как превратить эту строку в объект данного класса? Через JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() не получится - конвертер воспринимает строку как массив, но для массива содержимое получается слишком разнорордное и пасить строку, как object[] а потом приводить  каждый элемент своеобразного "массива" к классу мне кажется непрактичным решением.
Замена внешних скобок в строке и последующая десериализация как Json тоже не совсем подходит - читаю непрерывно данные из WebSocket и большое кол-во таких операций скажется на производительности приложения.
Есть ли более простое \ лаконичное \ каноничное для таких кейсов, решение?

простое \ лаконичное \ каноничное - это может быть три разных, иногда взаимоисключающих решений

Подтёр здесь дискуссию об ответах, автору напомню, что люди пишут ответы не только для вас, а в том чиле для будущих посетителей и сообщества. Важно получая ответы давать обратную связь если ответ не подоходит, во-первых чтобы у отвечающего была возможность его улучшить, во-вторых чтобы у него была возможность вам объяснить, если вы чего-то недопоняли. И в-третьих если вы нашли решение, которое лучше и эффективнее, чем существующие ответы на вопрос, опубликуйте его, оно может оказаться кому-то полезным, а ещё его можно обсудить с другими участниками. Забрасывать свои вопросы не стоит.

Я практически уверен, что эту "нетривиальную" строку сделали вы сами. Просто измените процесс сериализации, чтобы там не было массива. Ну или свяжитесь с теми, кто выдаёт такой JSON, пусть исправят.

А так, всё просто:
using System.Text.Json;

var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
var array = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object[]>(json);

var action = array[0].ToString();
var item = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PriceChangedItem>(array[1].ToString());

var response = new PriceChangedResponce
{
    Action = action,
    priceChangedItem = item
};

Да, это непрактично. Поэтому нужно исправлять генерацию исходного JSON.

Раз вы так почти уверены, вот вам адрес - bitskins.com.
Вот вам API - https://bitskins.com/ru/docs/api/v2#api-websocket.
Подключитесь к вебсокету, получите из него инфу.
Так же можете написать разработчикам площадки, чтобы выдавали json в легко перевариваемом формате. Не понимаю, зачем оставлять свои оценочные суждения в качестве мудрости. Был бы удобоваримый JSON, меня бы с данным вопросом здесь не было. Я думал, что здесь ресурс, на котором более опытные люди не строят из себя умников, а пытаются помочь решить проблему. Минус вам за комментарий.

А за ответ спасибо. Вполне коротко получилось.

Да частое дело это. Всякие апиписатели пишут на динамических языках типа пхп, где у них массив+словарь и у них конечно нет проблем с сериализацией и десериализацией. И исправлять таких апиписателей бесполезно - они просто не понимают.

Почему API должны исправлять просто потому, что JSON, который он выдает, пытаются десериализовать с помощью C#? Эта строка - валидный JSON массив, который можно распарсить. То, что возникают сложности с типизацией при десериализации - это проблема исключительно средств десериализации

@НиколайГончарик - оценочное суждение основано на многолетнем опыте. Много раз встречались подобные вопросы: "Есть нечто неудобоваримое. Как распарсить?" Начинаешь уточнять, откуда оно берётся, оказывается - создаётся автором вопросом (или его коллегами) в другом месте. Поэтому правильнее всего - исправить генерацию. ЗЫ: ну и привычная вишенка на торте: минус тому, кто помог (невежливо), а не тем, кто промолчал (вежливо).

@AndreiKhotko - согласно всем канонам разработки, массив - набор однотипных объектов. А тут - разные типы. Поэтому это не должен быть массив.

@AlexanderPetrov "исправить генерацию" - совсем не ответ. Уточнять нужно в комментах, где и выяснится что исправить невозможно. Так что минус вы таки заслужили за упрек автору не по теме.

@vitidev - у меня есть множество случаев здесь на SO, когда я в течение многих дней вытягивал из авторов уточняющую информацию. Вежливо и долго!.. А вот когда чуток подденешь, то сразу получаешь реакцию, пусть с соплями или возмущениями, но намного результативнее.

@vitidev - совсем не ответ. Вот есть легендарный ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5045688 Автор вопроса спросил: "Как распарсить html регулярками?" Получил ответ: "Ты не можешь, используй парсер". Да, по этому поводу неоднократно бывали обсуждения на мете, что делать: давать точный ответ, пусть и неправильный идеологически, или же советовать более правильный способ? Тут я выбрал способ: дать рабочий ответ и правильный совет.

@AlexanderPetrov полностью согласен, что по канонам разработки, массив это набор однотипных объектов. Но утверждать что я этот пример придумал сам... И что изменилось, от того, что вы с меня "вытянули" подробности? Да ничего. Просто показали, какой вы умный, результативности и эффективности это ничему не добавило.

Можно прочитать вот так.
public class PriceChangedResponceConverter : JsonConverter
{
    ...

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var action = reader.Value!.ToString()!;
        reader.Read();
        var item = serializer.Deserialize<PriceChangedItem>(reader)!;
        return new PriceChangedResponce { Action = action, priceChangedItem = item };
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(PriceChangedResponce) == objectType;
}

и читаем
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<PriceChangedResponce>>(json,
                                                  new PriceChangedResponceConverter());

upd: Вариант для System.Text.Json
А вот для System.Text.Json так просто не работает. Слишком придирается вместо того чтобы просто циклически вызывать конвертер. Приходится писать больше кода на более низком уровне и самому собирать список. Ну хоть для null он сам разберется и не нужно про него в конвертере думать (ура)
public class PriceChangedResponceConverter : JsonConverter<IList<PriceChangedResponce>>
{
    public override IList<PriceChangedResponce>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var items = new List<PriceChangedResponce>();
        while (true)
        {
            reader.Read();
            if(reader.TokenType==JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                break;
            var action = reader.GetString();
            reader.Read();
            var item = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PriceChangedItem>(ref reader)!;
            items.Add(new PriceChangedResponce { Action = action, priceChangedItem = item });
        }
        return items;
    }

    ...
}

и чтение
 var result =
     JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IList<PriceChangedResponce>>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions()
     {
         Converters = { new PriceChangedResponceConverter() }
     });


Utf8JsonReader/Writer познакомьтесь, очень полезная штука

@aepot Автор вопроса использует Newtonsoft. Хотя что Utf8JsonReader, что JsonReader из ньютонсофт - для них придется вручную писать портянку. Newtonsoft вот позволяет не писать, а для System.Text.Json решения пока не знаю.

Ошибся, увидел JsonSerializer и перепутал. А ещё эти Nullable аннотации намекают на свежий .NET, где JSON.NET мёртв.

@aepot А я вот его как раз и не заметил и потому создал лишний сам (отредактировал ответ и убрал лишнее). А ведь он готовый уже в метод передается. в System.Text.Json есть перегрузка JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref Utf8JsonReader reader), но у меня с ним не получается так же сделать.
